# conditional inline div styling (help!)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have div that I need to be present on every page, yet at a different length depending on the exact page.

So far, I have this:

`<div class="above <?php if (is_page(12)) echo 'short'; ?>"> //content </div><!-- end above -->`

How do I go about adding something to the avail of `<?php if (is_page(24, 26, 28)) echo 'med'; ?>`
(on page 12 I need the "short" length, and on pages 24, 26, 28 I need the "med" length of the div)

Any help is appreciated. I'm just now diving into php and while I do love the options it makes available, I'm not sure yet how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try somethng this:

```
<?php if (is_page(12)) { echo 'short';} elseif (is_page(array(24, 26, 28))){echo 'med';} ?>
```

See if this works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this and let me know then --

```
if ( is_page(array(24, 26, 28) ) ) {
.....
.....
}

else {
}
```